# Grant deny permission stacking

Tags: sql-server, permissions, role

For the role `db_denycustomer`, I want *only* the column code of the customer table to be SELECTable, and none of the others. So I did this:

```
DENY SELECT ON dbo.customer TO db_denycustomer
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.customer (code) TO db_denycustomer
```

...and it works fine. Cool! But, **why**?

What I've read in related articles is that permissions stack, but `DENY` takes precedence. In contrast, in my case, it seems that the last permission "query" took precedence. Sure enough, if I execute them in reverse order, the latter `DENY` hides the code column too.

Could you please elaborate on this?

I have also included the default `db_datawriter` and `db_datareader` roles to the user that I tested with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql) provided for backwards compatibility. Documentation excerpt:

> **Caution** A table-level DENY does not take precedence over a
>   column-level GRANT. This inconsistency in the permissions hierarchy
>   has been preserved for backward compatibility.